# Security risk of using a budgeting app connected to bank accounts

Tags: account-security, budget

I've been tracking my budget the old way for a few years now by using excel spread sheets that have my checking account ledger, and monthly expenses broken down to categories. But I have noticed more people have moved to using apps to track their budget and some of these also connect to their bank accounts, which to me seems sketchy isn't this a big security risk? ( It was suggested I ask this question here from SE Personal finance and money)

Comment: Simple Google search with the title of your question: https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/7-tips-using-budget-apps-safely-1282.php

https://www.thestreet.com/personal-finance/is-mint-safe-14814998

https://www.moneysense.ca/save/budgeting/mint-budgeting-app-safe/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/198005/3365) about Plaid, which underlies budget trackers like Mint.  Short version: Yes, it's a security trade-off.

Comment: @gowenfawr thank you for the link, I will look at it now...sorry if I broke community rules, still getting the hang of SE

Comment: @ProgrammingByDay You didn't break any community rules.  A downvote just means that someone didn't like your particular question, and that just happens sometimes (for a variety of reasons).  I think the answer to the question gowenfawr linked to is going to give you the best answer you can get here, so hopefully that will get you off to a good start!